# rails - assign preexisting record as nested association while updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, accepts-nested-attributes

I am not using a rails form as this is all coming from an XML that I am parsing. For my requirement, I need to assign an existing record as nested association while at the same time, updating selected attributes of that association.

My models are the following:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :listings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings, inverse_of: :user
  belongs_to :agency, inverse_of: :users
end

class Agency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :agency
end
```

Now, to assign an existing user record, my listing params should be

```
params = { user_id: 1230 }
```

To include user record attribute changes, my listing params should be:

```
params = { user_attributes: { agency_id: 3453 } }
```

Then of course I do the assignment and save:

```
listing.assign_attributes(params)
listing.save
```

Using only the former params doesn't allow me to do the `agency_id` update in the same database transaction; while using the latter params creates a new user record.

My original attempt was to merge the two param sets somehow:

```
params = { user_attributes: { id: 1230, agency_id: 3453 } }
```

This resulted in the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID= 1230 for PropertyListing with ID=
```

Sidenote: I would like to be able to support both update and create actions with the same params set.

Since that didn't work I tried another hybrid:

```
params = { user_id: 1230, user_attributes: { agency_id: 3453 } }
```

But this one also created a new user with the correct `agency_id`, while ignoring the `user_id` attribute.

Is there a way to assign the existing `User.find(1230)` while updating the same user's `agency_id` in the same ActiveRecord DB request and params set?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your models and the association between those models?